# Find $P(X>2,Y<4)$ where the joint pdf is $f(x, y)= e^{-y}$ if $ 0<x<y<\infty$ and $0$ otherwise

Tags: probability

Let $(X, Y)$ be a random vector with joint density function given by

$$f(x, y)=\begin{cases}\mathrm e^{-y} & \text { if } & 0<x<y<\infty \\[1ex]
0 && \text { otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

Find $P(X>2,Y<4)$

I think it is $\displaystyle\int_2^4\int _x^4\mathrm e^{-y}\:\mathrm dy\:\mathrm dx$, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Your integral looks good to me

Answer (score 1):

Since $X<Y$ almost surely, then you indeed want:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\,{>}\,2, Y\,{<}\,4)&=\mathsf P(2\,{<}\,X\,{<}\,Y\,{<}\,4)\\[1ex] & =\int_2^4\int_x^4 \mathrm e^{-y}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\int_2^4\int_2^y \mathrm e^{-y}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$$